# Intellij IDEA GUI Designer: form file is invalid

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, gui-designer

Faced such problem: GUI Designer does not show some forms. This happened after the transition to the new version of IDEA (2023.1.4 (Community Edition)). My colleagues who use the old version does not have this problem. The form itself writes that it cannot init class (see screenshot), but the same colleagues do not have the same package. There is also a reference to this class in the IDEA logs. The official GitHub account of IntellijIdea has this package. In theory, perhaps it can be downloaded and put into classPath, or roll back the IDE version, but maybe someone knows a more elegant solution to this problem?

```
2023-07-25 16:06:55,038 [108516339]   INFO - #c.i.u.d.GuiEditor - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.radComponents.RadComponent.<init>(RadComponent.java:147)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.radComponents.RadContainer.<init>(RadContainer.java:75)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.radComponents.RadToolBar.<init>(RadToolBar.java:31)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.XmlReader.createComponent(XmlReader.java:131)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.XmlReader.createComponent(XmlReader.java:224)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.XmlReader.createComponent(XmlReader.java:224)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.XmlReader.createComponent(XmlReader.java:224)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.XmlReader.createRoot(XmlReader.java:47)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.designSurface.GuiEditor.readFromFile(GuiEditor.java:867)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.designSurface.GuiEditor.<init>(GuiEditor.java:296)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.editor.UIFormEditor.<init>(UIFormEditor.java:44)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.editor.UIFormEditorProvider.createEditor(UIFormEditorProvider.java:34)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.createComposite(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:1139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.doOpenInEdtImpl(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:1048)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.doOpenInEdtImpl$default(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:1035)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl$openFileImpl4$open$1.invoke(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:1010)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl$openFileImpl4$open$1.invoke(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:996)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl$Companion.runBulkTabChange$intellij_platform_ide_impl(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:390)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl4$open(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:996)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl4$intellij_platform_ide_impl(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:1024)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl2$lambda$22(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:900)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:210)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:174)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl2(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:899)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFile(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:798)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openEditorImpl$lambda$31(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:1275)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:210)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:174)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openEditorImpl(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:1268)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileEditor(FileEditorManagerImpl.kt:1245)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.FileEditorManager.openEditor(FileEditorManager.java:239)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.FileNavigatorImpl.navigateInAnyFileEditor(FileNavigatorImpl.java:110)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.FileNavigatorImpl.navigateInEditor(FileNavigatorImpl.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.FileNavigatorImpl.navigateInEditorOrNativeApp(FileNavigatorImpl.java:71)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.FileNavigatorImpl.navigate(FileNavigatorImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.OpenFileDescriptor.navigate(OpenFileDescriptor.java:89)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.navigate(PsiFileImpl.java:926)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.navigation.NavigationUtil.lambda$openFileWithPsiElement$2(NavigationUtil.java:173)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:219)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:174)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:150)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.navigation.NavigationUtil.openFileWithPsiElement(NavigationUtil.java:169)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.AbstractPsiBasedNode.navigate(AbstractPsiBasedNode.java:277)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.AbstractPsiBasedNode.navigate(AbstractPsiBasedNode.java:287)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.PsiFileNode.navigate(PsiFileNode.java:117)
    at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.navigateToSource(OpenSourceUtil.java:126)
    at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.navigate(OpenSourceUtil.java:81)
    at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.navigate(OpenSourceUtil.java:59)
    at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.navigate(OpenSourceUtil.java:52)
    at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.openSourcesFrom(OpenSourceUtil.java:20)
    at com.intellij.util.EditSourceOnDoubleClickHandler$TreeMouseListener.processDoubleClick(EditSourceOnDoubleClickHandler.java:172)
    at com.intellij.util.EditSourceOnDoubleClickHandler$TreeMouseListener.onDoubleClick(EditSourceOnDoubleClickHandler.java:166)
    at com.intellij.ui.DoubleClickListener.onClick(DoubleClickListener.java:30)
    at com.intellij.ui.ClickListener$1.mouseReleased(ClickListener.java:58)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:298)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6656)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
    at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree.processMouseEvent(Tree.java:424)
    at com.intellij.ide.dnd.aware.DnDAwareTree.processMouseEvent(DnDAwareTree.java:44)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6421)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5026)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2804)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:790)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:763)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:761)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:760)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:667)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:615)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:570)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:68)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:349)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:348)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:343)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:995)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:995)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$4(IdeEventQueue.kt:343)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:829)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sYoe.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDlWu.png)

In theory, perhaps it can be downloaded and put into classPath, or roll back the IDE version.

Comment: Please share your form file for testing at https://uploads.jetbrains.com and provide the UploadID here

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I think I can't do it becouse it's a commercial product, but the solution of problem was to roll back the IDE version (to 2021.3.3).  Before it I update IDE to 2023.2 and there was anoter problem (IDE could't find my class with icons)